# PTIJ: Why do people wear yarmukas publicizing that Rav Nachman was trained?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Lately, I've been seeing many people wearing yarmulkas that say:

נחמן מאומן - (Rav) Nachman, the trained

I think we can assume that Nachman was trained to be a rav. Even if he was trained in other things, why does that need to be publicized on a yarmulka?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the first part of the quote:

> ננח נחום נחמן מאומן

נח of course is a euphemism for death, as in the phrase in various Gemaras נח נפשיה.

The term אומן is reminiscent of two quotes from Kiddushin. The first is its final Mishnah:

> רַבִּי נְהוֹרַאי אוֹמֵר, מַנִּיחַ אֲנִי כָּל אֻמָּנוּת שֶׁבָּעוֹלָם וְאֵינִי מְלַמֵּד אֶת בְּנִי אֶלָּא תוֹרָה
>
> Rebbe Nehorai said: I put aside all trades in the world, and I only teach my son Torah.

The second is a Braisa on 29a:

> רבי יהודה אומר כל (שאינו) מלמד את בנו אומנות מלמדו ליסטות
>
> R’ Yehudah says, whoever teaches his son a trade teaches him thievery.

(Many readings include שאינו in this teaching; Haghos HaPurim Rav takes it out.)

What we see here is that being trained is a bad thing.

Now, what kind of training did נחמן have? Well, apparently his full name was נחום נחמן, and, [as we know](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80373/), נחום was a candle maker whose candles are forbidden for Shabbos candles.

Seemingly, these yarmulkes are warning others: don’t be trained in a trade. After all,

> ננח נחום נחמן מאומן
>
> Nachum Nachman, the trained, died.

Comment: Really funny logic! Like me, I think you've been hanging around the Bet Midrash a little too much ;-)

Answer (score 1):

נחמן מאומן may be roughly translated to `the trained psychologist`, or `comforter`. The message on the yarmulke refers to the fact that although Ukraine is not yet covered under [EuroPsy](http://www.europsy.eu) (or European Certificate in Psychology), he is still certified in one of their other two dozen or so covered countries.

Comment: This was one of the few times that I laughed at something I don't completely understand. Can you explain how you get "psychologist" from the reference. There's a hidden translation that I don't follow. I think you should edit that in the answer.

Comment: נחמן - as in נחמו נחמו עמי אמר...

Comment: OK - "comforter" I get, now. But "psychologist"?